# Alternate messaging infrastructure

Tags: whisper, message

How can organizations with existing messaging infrastructures integrate with Ethereum?

For example, an organization with a large investment in Solace Messaging asked us how to integrate Ethereum into their existing event-based infrastructure.

Can the Framework based on the Whisper Protocol in Ethereum be replaced with a centralized event based platform?

Can the Framework based on the Whisper Protocol in Ethereum be configured to use the Solace Platform or other messaging platforms like ActiveMQ that support AMQP 1.0?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you intend to do with these queueing systems. What part of Ethereum would you like to connect to the queue, for what benefit. Then we will see if it's possible. Otherwise, the basic computer stuff answer will be yes as anything is possible with computers...